# Not able to draw a Pie Chart with external csv file in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, csv, highcharts

I tried  drawing a pie chart with external csv  in HIGHCHARTS, but its not coming up properly , instead of labels name  only slice is coming up.

I have created a fiddle for this [pie fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BHUPENDRA1011/dsbvpkt0/5/), fiddle works for other chart options like 'bar','line' etc but fails for 'pie' option.

below is the graph option that is set in fiddle :

```
var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'pie'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Vechicle Sales'                 
            },

            xAxis: {
                categories: []
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Sales'
                }
            },
            series: []
        };
```

Please let me know what would be reason behind this and what would be correct processing for csv file.

Thanks

Comment: You have 3 series, which means 3 pie charts. It is your goal, or single chart ?

Comment: Hi Sebastian , I require all these values a in single pie chart.is it possible

Comment: If not possible , then I could have a pie with single series  , here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BHUPENDRA1011/dsbvpkt0/6/ for that .Instead of slice how can I have label on this.. Thanks

Comment: You want a single pie chart, but your data doesn't make sense for that.  Your data is vechiles by year, pie charts usually only represent one variable.  So, how do you want it, by year or by vechile?  Say, by year, do you sum then?  Average? Median?

Comment: HI mark , it would be sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code takes each year as a series with each vechile type as an xaxis category.  This is inapproapriate for a pie chart since it needs to be a single series of datapoints.  So, we'll need to switch up the CSV parsing:

```
var seriesData = []; // this will be an array of point objects
var lines = csvData.split('\n');

$.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
  var items = line.split(',');

  if (lineNo === 0) { // first line contains point names
    $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
      //skip first item of first line
      if (itemNo > 0) {
        seriesData.push({
          name: item,
          y: 0
        }); // create a data point object
      }
    });
  } else {

    $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
      if (itemNo > 0) {
        // find our data point and sum the values
        seriesData[itemNo - 1]['y'] += parseFloat(item);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Finally add this data as a single series:

```
options.series.push({data: seriesData, name: 'Vehicle'});
```

Working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/dsbvpkt0/7/).